# Create Hierarchy Recursive using multiple table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, recursive-query

I want to make a query that shows employee below manager.
using 5 tables on SQL.
Here is the example of my databases.

```
Department Table
id         dept         parent
1          HR
2          Financial      1
3          Research       1
4          Loans          2
5          Marketing      3

Role Table
id         role         parent
1          Commissioner    
2          Director       1
3          Manager        2
4          Supervisor     3
5          Staff          4

deptrole Table
id         iddept       idrole
1            1            1
2            1            2
3            1            3
4            1            4
5            1            5

Biography Table
id         name         regnumber
1          Bob             N1
2          John            N2
3          Roxy            N3
4          Ian             N4
5          Will            N5

Employee Table
id         IdBio       deptrole
1            1            3
2            2            1
3            3            2
4            4            5
5            5            4
```

when i input id on Query (WHERE EmpId = 1),its shows who's the employee below id 1,so it would be EmpId 5 and then 4.and when EmpId = 2,the child is EmpId 3-1-5-4.
how did i do that ?

Comment: i already make a query for showing department child,but i dont know how do i put all of these together.i dont know where to start.if only i know the steps of doing this,i could make a new query @PawełDyl

Comment: There is no relationship between employees. How do you find the link between Employees 3-1-5-4 ?

Comment: the relationnship i make is One to Many (role -> IdRole, dept -> IdDept).that is what i want to achieve,finding the link where EmpId "4" =3-1-5-4 @Polux2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to have understood the whole problem but you can try this.

```
Declare @empid as int;
SET @empid = 1;

With A as 
(
    Select id as Subord_role
    from role
    WHERE role.parent = (Select deptrole.idrole
                            FROM Employee
                                INNER JOIN deptrole ON deptrole.id = Employee.id
                            WHERE Employee.id = @empid)
    UNION ALL

    Select Role.id
    from deptrole 
        INNER JOIN Role ON deptrole.idrole = Role.id
        INNER JOIN A ON A.Subord_role = Role.parent
    Where deptrole.iddept = (Select deptrole.iddept
                            FROM Employee
                                INNER JOIN deptrole ON deptrole.id = Employee.id
                            WHERE Employee.id = @empid)
)

Select Employee.id
FROM Employee
    INNER JOIN deptrole ON deptrole.id = Employee.id
    INNER JOIN Role ON role.id = deptrole.idrole 
    INNER JOIN A ON A.Subord_role = Role.id
```

Comment: i got this error : Must declare the scalar variable "@empid".

Comment: Scalar Variable is Fixed,another error : "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 10000 has been exhausted before statement completion." .I already set max recursion to 0,10000,and 32767,and all still exhausted to process the looping @Polux2

Comment: I've made fixes on my query and now it works. Sorry.